# Split a PayPal payment into multiple payments to the same receiver

Tags: c#, paypal, nopcommerce

I manage a nopCommerce site that uses the PayPal Express checkout plugin. Our accounting department wants the ability to split the payments based on some business rules. This differs from PayPal’s Adaptive Payments because in this case it’s multiple payments for the same receiver. Ultimately, I would need to capture the transaction IDs for each payment to process later on.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your goal here.  Multiple payments for the same receiver..??  Can you provide an example of use case?  Not sure I see the point..??

Comment: We want to take what would be the order total and split that into 2 more more separate transactions.  So for example, lets say the order total at checkout is $100, but we want to split that into 2 $50 transactions.  Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of splitting a transaction into two if you're sending both transactions to the same PayPal account?

In order to do that you would need to setup a [billing agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) for the buyer and then use reference transactions to process the two transactions separately.

It has a message that those APIs are being deprecated soon, but that's not really true.  Indeed, they are trying to get people to move to the REST APIs instead of the Classic APIs, however, Classic is still so heavily used (and still has functionality that REST simply doesn't have) that they aren't going to be eliminating them.  I still use Classic APIs primarily myself.

Comment: The reason for this request is that we have a Nop to Dynamics GP integration setup.  Some of the Nop orders get split into 2 or more seperate GP orders, but this caused issues for our accounting department because they can't reconcile the order totals with the credit card transaction amount.  What is this billing agreement you refer to?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a doc that outlines it.